# List opened files grouped by pending changelist in p4

Tags: bash, cygwin, perforce, changelist

In Cygwin bash, how can I list all files opened in the current workspace grouped by pending changelist (ignoring empty or shelved changelists)?

For example, if I've the following files opened in the following changelists, I wish to display it in this (or similar) format:

```
1234: Changelist 1234's description
//path1/file1 1 add  text
//path2/file2 2 edit text

5678: Changelist 5678's description
//path2/file3 3 edit xbinary
```

`p4 opened|sed "s/\([-#()]\|change\)/ /g"|column -t|sort -k 4` sort-of groups them by changelist number:

```
//path1/file1 1 add  1234 text
//path2/file2 2 edit 1234 text
//path2/file3 3 edit 5678 xbinary
```

but I'd like to see each changelist number and description as a header.

Comment: Why not use a real scripting language for this? Pick your favorite (Perl, Python, Ruby, etc.) and use the Perforce bindings for your scripting language to make things easy.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest approach would be something like this:

```
p4 changes -s pending -c $P4CLIENT | awk '{print $2}' | p4 -x - describe -s
```

This lists all pending changes for your current client (aka workspace) and calls `p4 describe -s`.

Comment: Thanks! It's almost what I need, except that it lists pending changelists without any opened files. Is there a way to list only changelists with opened files?

Comment: Hm. I can't think of any simple solution for that. Maybe pipe it through sed and filter out lines starting with "Change" that are followed by another line starting with "Change".

Comment: How about: `p4 -Ztag -F %change% opened | uniq | p4 -x - describe -s`

Answer (score 3):

This is my piece of code in .bashrc to create a p4pending alias to achieve the similar goal. I use 'p4 changes' to generate the header for each changelist, and 'p4 opened -c' to list the files opened in the changelist. This gives me pretty much same result as I get in P4V.

```
__desc_chg()
{
   echo "$1"
   num=`echo $1 | awk '{print $2}'`
   p4 opened -c $num 2>&1 | awk '{print "        "$1,$2,$3,$6}'
   echo 
}

__p4pending()
{
   __desc_chg "Change default by $P4USER@$P4CLIENT *pending*" 
   p4 changes -u $P4USER -c $P4CLIENT -s pending | sort -k2 -n | while read -r l; do __desc_chg "$l"; done
}

alias p4pending='__p4pending'
```